# How to handle wrong user input for BigDecimal

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Im writting JAVA code and I have user input that is BigDecimal. Previously I wrote do while check for integer input like this:

```
        int number= 0;
        do {
            System.out.print("Enter number: ");
            number= scan.nextInt();
        }
        while (number< 0);
```

And now I have BigDecimal user input

```
        BigDecimal price = scan.nextBigDecimal();
        scan.nextLine();
```

How to handle wrong user input like with int, for example if user enters -10,00 or if he enters 10.00 (it should be 10,00)?

Comment: First find out how the error is reported to the program (the documentation is a great source for that). Second handle the error in whatever way you like.

Answer (score 2):

The Scanner class has capabilities to scan numbers in different locales, for this you can use methods useLocale() and reset(). In addition you can call hasNextBigDecimal() method which returns true/false.

Comment: [`hasNextBigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextBigInteger--).  Check it out; it will be your friend here.

Comment: How would you wrap price exactly? To return user on input again with message about not vaid entery and offer him to input it again? I googled it but it is not clear for me :(

Answer (score 0):

**< operator** is undefined in BigDecimal, so you have to use **compareTo()** method.The return value of compareTo() are 0,-1 and 1.

> **Returns:** **-1**, **0**, or **1** as this BigDecimal is numerically less than, equal to, or greater than val.

Comment: How would you wrap then BigDecimal scan input for price? To return user on input again with message about not vaid entery and offer him to input it again?

Comment: I have added new answer with explanation along with code. Hope it helps to solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

> Check out below code.

1. At first, price is taken as input and **converted into BigDecimal**.
2. Then that converted price is compared using **compareTo()** method to check whether the price is positive or negative
3. If price is positive, leave the price as it is else converted to negative.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter price");
        BigDecimal price = scan.nextBigDecimal();

        if (price.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) > 0) {
            System.out.println("Price is greater than 0(positive)");

             /*....Write your business logic....*/

        } else if (price.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) < 0) {
            System.out.println("Price is less than 0(negative)");

            /* This line converts negative price to positive */
            price = price.multiply(new BigDecimal("-1"));

            /*....Write your business logic....*/

        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I was thinking about handling it more like to return user on previous step if he enters input wrong, and to check it maybe with hasNextBigDecimal() method, just I am not sure how to implement it... I tried but I think I created infinite loop :/

Comment: @Matej u can upvote answers, so that it will help others to find solution easily